# Add dynamic transcluded content

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to accomplish the following scenario:

I've got the following directive:

```
return {
   restrict: "AE",
   replace: true,
   transclude: true,
   scope: {
       chartData: "=",
       groupId: "@", 
       groupName: "@"
    },
    template: "<div class=\"flex\" ng-transclude></div>",
    compile: function(){
          var charts = [];

        return function (scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn) {
            _.forEach(scope.chartData, function (data) {
                var id = "gauge-" + scope.groupId + '-' + data.name;

                scope[id] = data.value; // gauge directive can now access this value
                element.append("<div class=\"flex-spacer flex-column\"><div bv-gauge chart-title=\"" + data.name + "\" data-value=\"" + scope[id] + "\" series-name=\"" + scope.groupName + "\"></div></div>");

                charts.push(id);
            });

            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            scope.$watch("chartData", function (newVal) {
                _.forEach(scope.chartData, function (data) {
                    var id = "gauge-" + scope.groupName + '-' + data.name;

                    scope.$broadcast("chart:update", newVal);
                });
            });
        }

    }
 };
```

As you can see I'm adding dynamically some content to the directive's element. It works nice but there is one issue; the isolated scope of inner directives ( i.e. bv-gauge) can see the outer scope only not the scope of bv-gauge-parent; As far as I know this is the default behaviour, which we can override by using the transclude function.

However, it seems that angular doesn't consider the dynamically added content as part of the transcluded content. So when I do the following:

```
transcludeFn(scope, function(clone, scope){
 // clone doesn't have the content we added earlier
});
```

Is there any way to associate the scope of the transcluded content with the parent directive?

Comment: Can gauges be added/removed dynamically on the fly? If yes, you may have to have a look at how ng-repeat is implemented.

Comment: I think with ng-repeat you set the translcuded content statically.